# Temporary files are not getting deleted in Apache Jackrabbit

Tags: java, apache, jcr, jackrabbit

I am using `Apache Jackrabbit` to store PDF, doc files and using `FileDataStore` as underlying data store. After setting the binary data values many temporary/spool files (bin*.tmp) are getting created in the temp directory. These files are never getting deleted until JVM is getting shutdown. These temp files are flooding the tmp directory and resulting to a `no space left on device` error.

Following is the code snippet:

```
Node childFileNode = childLeafFolder.addNode(file.pdf, NodeType.NT_FILE);
Node childContentNode = childFileNode.addNode(Node.JCR_CONTENT,
                    NodeType.NT_RESOURCE);
Property property = childContentNode.setProperty(Property.JCR_DATA, binary);
```

I have tried invoking `property.getBinary.dispose()`, which points to `AbstractQValue dispose()`, and find out that it is an empty method.

I have googled and came across [JCR-3568](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCR-3568%20%20JCR-3568) and this is still unresolved. My application runs for long duration and it can not be shutdown frequently.

Looks like I am missing some thing as this could be a very common issue.

Comment: Hi, I'm also facing the same issue. No space left on device. Can anyone suggest in which version will JCR-3568 be addressed.

Comment: Write a unit test. Fix the bug. Propose a patch. It's open source.

Answer (score 0):

There is resource leak in jackrabbit-spi-commons library, and it still not fixed. When you write file to server and file size more than 64kb, client library creates 2 copy of original file in temporary folder, but deletes only 1.
While it not fixed, you can use workaround:

```
public class JcrHelper {
    public static Value createBinaryValue(Session jcrSession, InputStream in) throws UnsupportedRepositoryOperationException, RepositoryException {
        ValueFactory valueFactory = jcrSession.getValueFactory();
        Value value = valueFactory.createValue(in);
        return value;
    }
    public static void discardBinary(Value value) {
        if (value instanceof QValueValue) {
            QValueValue qValueValue = (QValueValue)value;
            qValueValue.getQValue().discard();
        }
    }
}
```

and in code you should use Value instead Binary:

```
Value value = JcrHelper.createBinaryValue(jcrSession, inputStream);
try {
    contentNode.setProperty(Property.JCR_DATA, value);
    jcrSession.save();
} finally {
    JcrHelper.discardBinary(value);
}
```

JcrHelper class uses deprecated method, and violates encapsulation, but code not leaky. I think its only possible workaround while leak in Binary implementation not fixed.
Furthermore, this code creates only 1 copy of your file in temp folder (will be deleted on GC)